# xcode 4.2.1 - subclassing UITextView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextview, subclass

how can I subclass UITextView to disable copy,cut,and paste?

I have seen many examples out there but I did not get how to subclass UITextView?

I need to overwrite:

```
    - (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
   return NO;
}
```

But what is the exact steps to subclass ? and how to link it to my existing UITextView in my storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% about this, but it may work.

On your subclass, override this method like this:

```
-(BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)selector withSender:(id)sender{
  if(selector == @selector(copy) || selector == @selector(cut) || selector == @selector(paste)) return NO;
  return [super canPerformAction:selector withSender:sender];
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to subclass just to stop user interaction.  Just set the userInteractionEnabled property to NO.